# Why does C# 4.5 async/await WebClient require lambda methodology when using StreamReader ReadToEndAsync?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, webclient, async-await

Given:

```
    public async Task<string> SendRequest(this string url)
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var buffer = e.Result;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(buffer)))
            {
                var result = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            };
        };
        wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
}
```

The statement:

```
var result = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
```

Shows an error in the designer as follows: "The await operator can only be used within an async lambda expression"

[image]

I don't understand why this message is happening, when I look at all ReadToEndAsync examples they look exactly like this code.

Please advise...

Comment: The lamda (which is not an Expression here) itself *is* a method, hidden away and faked to allow access to the bindings in the containing scope. And `await` can only be used in `async` methods (or said async lambdas-come-methods).

Comment: It's not requiring lambda, it's requiring async method or async lambda. You don't _need_ a lambda.

Comment: your await is not corresponding to the outer method, but to the lambda, and the lambda is not async.

Comment: This stems from the decision to suffix library async/await Task based methods with `Async`. However, in the case of the `WebClient`, there were already methods ending in `Async` as you have discovered, so in this case, the naming is more explicit with suffix `TaskAsync`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a WebClient with the TPL, you should be using the methods with `Task` in the name, to get `Task` returning methods rather than using the event based mode (which you then would need to transform into tasks):

```
public static async Task<string> SendRequest(this string url)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var bytes = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MichalCiechan I'm surprised it took you so long to downvote a correct answer so that your incorrect answer could more prominently convey incorrect information to anyone who might actually be looking for a solution to the problem.  Clearly you're only here to troll other users and try to actively make other people's lives worse just for the fun of it.

Comment: Haha, how started with the negativity? Have you tried compiling your answer? As you like to say: IT DOESN'T EVEN COMPILE! Anyway please tell me why my answer is wrong? Yes i don't know why, and i cannot see why. Only thing is im not 100% sure if you return await Task<T> does it block straight away? Or only on await? And no im not 100% proficient in TPL.... sorry...

Comment: @MichalCiechan You most certainly can.  I have no idea why you would think that you couldn't.

Comment: Yes sorry, was trying to compile from a nested class :|

Comment: @MichalCiechan Your answer is wrong because the method needs to return a `Task<string>`, and it doesn't.  Nothing is returned, and a significant rework of the method would be required to *allow* it to be able to return the actual value.  Marking the event handler as `async` makes the use of `await` in the handler compile, but it does nothing to make the method (outside the lambda) pause execution until after the `await`, as that's all going on in the lambda, not the method itself.  The OP was trying to have it pause the outer method, but that isn't what's actually happening.

Comment: +1 for explanation, yes true, it wouldnt pause the outer method, only the anonymous function(lambda). What is wrong with my answer? It achieves what he wants.. see edit 2 ;-)

Comment: @MichalCiechan the second edit is fundamentally the same as the previous.  As I told you in a comment a long time ago, there is no reason for the method to be marked as `async`, the way you had it.  It's neither a noticeable improvement nor a problem, it's *primarily* stylistic.  Again, try and compile your first snippet.  Fix the obvious and trivial mistakes, and then see that there are bigger problems that won't be so easily solved.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between them ;-)

Comment: Not adding the extra await, returns immedately, before giving up CPU time to the child Task. Adding the await, immediately give CPU time to the child Task. As my tests show :-) Or if multi core environment, it spawns a schedules the task slightly later

Comment: @MichalCiechan Either you're referring to the fact that the second is `static` and the first wasn't, that's contrary to your comment, and given that the first really needs to be static, not particularly meaningful.  Other than that, any exceptions thrown in the second case when constructing the `WebClient` will be thrown from the method, rather than wrapped in the returned task, but that's pretty unlikely to happen.  It's why I said they're *basically* the same and not *exactly* the same.

Comment: @MichalCiechan No, that's not true.  Both methods do exactly the same amount of work synchronously, and exactly the same amount of work synchronously, except that the `async` method has to spend a tinsy bit of extra synchronous effort spinning up a new state machine, which I doubt is what you're concerned with.  Both methods construct the `WebClient` synchronously, both synchronously wait for `DownloadStringTaskAsync` to build its task, and both yield control to the caller as soon as that happens, marking the returned task as completed (asynchronously) when the operation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Task<string> SendRequest(this string url)
    {
        return (new WebClient()).DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
```

Comment: Ya didn't get to the return yet because I'm trying to understand this issue... You know,  code as you go...

Comment: 1. What was the problem? A. Making Lambda Async
2. Did the original code compile? A. No
3. Did the author Complain it didnt compile? A. No
4. What was the solution to this question? A. Adding async keyword in front of the lambda
5. Does my initial answer solve THIS question? A. Yes
6. Let me remind you of the question - I don't understand why this message is happening (The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.)

Comment: Looks like you gave up on trying to fix the first snippet.  It's not impossible of course, it's just a fair bit of work.

Comment: no, didnt even attempt, found it pointless, will leave that as an excercise for another day. Anyhow im off now, and thanks, I learnt 1 new thing return await Task<T> doesn't actually block :-D